# Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference when using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP PDO to insert into a MYSQL database using PHP. I am getting the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in
>   /home/sandyit/public_html/hosting/findibuzz/design2/sign-up.php on
>   line 200

This is my code:

$ID is an auto incremented integer while the rest are varchar variables filled out as below as an example:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'dbusername', 'dbpass');

$FULLNAME = "David";
$PW_HASH = "sadsad";
$SALT = "adadad";
$EMAIL_ADDRESS = "david@gmail.com";


$ID=0;
$addrequest = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO FB_USERS (ID,FULL_NAME,PASSWORD,PASSWORD_SALT,EMAIL_ADDRESS) VALUES (:ID,:FULL_NAME,:PASSWORD,:PASSWORD_SALT,:EMAIL_ADDRESS)");
$addrequest->bindParam(':ID',$ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$addrequest->bindParam(':FULL_NAME',$FULL_NAME, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$addrequest->bindParam(':PASSWORD',$PW_HASH, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$addrequest->bindParam(':PASSWORD_SALT',$SALT, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$addrequest->bindParam(':EMAIL_ADDRESS',$EMAIL_ADDRESS, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$addrequest->execute();
$addrequest->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

I know i have something wrong, but i cannot spot the error, can i have some advise please?

Thanks

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for reference. I know this wont help solve your problem, but you could do something like this (see code below) to achieve the same result:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'dbusername', 'dbpass');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "INSERT INTO FB_USERS (FULL_NAME,PASSWORD,PASSWORD_SALT,EMAIL_ADDRESS)
        VALUES (:FULL_NAME,:PASSWORD,:PASSWORD_SALT,:EMAIL_ADDRESS)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$params = array
(
    'FULL_NAME'=>'David',
    'PASSWORD'=>'sadsad',
    'PASSWORD_SALT'=>'adadad',
    'EMAIL_ADDRESS'=>'david@gmail.com'
);
$stmt->execute($params)
```

I find it easier to work with an array and than to just pass it to the statment.
But I guess its just a mather of taste.
Like I said this is just for reference and wont help you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Remove quotation marks from `'$ID'`

```
$addrequest->bindParam(':ID',$ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Not sure but i think he could remove the ':' from ':ID'

Comment: @Sebastien The `:` is optional.

Comment: @Sebastien You're welcome. TBH, I didn't know that neither till about 4-5 months ago.

Comment: That has helped, thanks for pointing out those mistakes, what happens now is that the script runs, there are no errors generated but no entries are entered into the database.

Comment: I think this is my first column is auto incremented and is a primary key, but i can't figure out what im doing wrong?

Comment: @user3657758 What `$addrequest->execute();` returns?

Comment: If your first colomn is auto increment dont bind a parameter to it.

Comment: That is part of the problem, i do not get any errors returned. Could this be as my first column is auto incremented and has a primary key and it does not like this value when entering a new entry into the table?

Comment: @user3657758 it's all right to send 0 for this column

Comment: It can have, but mysql automatically replace it